# Django python manage.py syncdb

Tags: python, django

I get following error after I try to sync with the database:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/src/signups/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class SignUp(models.Model):
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/src/signups/models.py", line 10, in SignUp
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_not=False)
  File "/home/vitaly/Documents/skillshare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 737, in __init__
    Field.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_not'
```

I'm new to Django, so I really have no idea what to think of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a typo, instead of `auto_not`, you probably meant `auto_now`.

Replace

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_not=False)
```

with:

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

Comment: Actually `False` is the default for both `auto_now_add` and `auto_now`, so better is just to remove `auto_now` entirely.

Comment: @CarlMeyer good point, thank you. Though one could say "explicit is better than implicit"..